# Uniqueness of rotational symmetry of a link diagram

Tags: knot-theory

How can I prove that a connected link diagram can only admit up to one axis perpendicular to the plane through which rotational symmetry lies, i.e there aren't rotational symmetries through different axes in the same diagram?

Comment: Just to make sure: are you referring to the link diagram of a knot, as at the page http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinkDiagram.html ?

Comment: Yes, but we can allow for multiple components as in a link. When there is only one component, this is a knot diagram.

Answer (score 0):

**An idea:** There is presumably a finite set $A$ of places where the crossings occur. If the knot is rotation invariant about a point $P$, then so is the finite set $A.$ I would also guess you want to say the least angle $\theta$ of the rotation is of the form $2\pi/n$ so that the knot has symmetry under rotation through $\theta$ [other choices for $\theta$ would give infinitely many points in $A$, I think...]

Now each point $a\in A$ is rotated by $\theta$ around $P$ to another point in $A$, and after doing the rotation $n$ times one has for that $a$ a set of points on a regular $n$ gon centered at $P$. I think this means that $P$ must be the centroid of the collection of points in $A$. Then since a finite set has a unique centroid you could conclude the uniqueness of the rotation center from this.

Note some things need filling in here, this is just an idea of how it might be approached.

Comment: How about if the link diagram was on $S^{2}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Comment: @user4506 In case of $S^2$ as the space, a rotation would be about a line through the center of the sphere and a pair of antipodal points $P,-P$. If so one could maybe stereographically project from $-P$ onto the tangent plane at $P$ and then use the centroid idea. [It then becomes less obvious such a center is unique, since calculation of the centroid depends on the point of the sphere projected from.]

Comment: @user4506 Actually if $A$ is the set of vertices of a regular solid inscribed in the sphere $S^2$, then any (nonreflectional) symmetry of the solid which amounts to a rotation about a line through its center is an axis of symmetry of the set $A$ as a subset of $S^2$.

Comment: @coffeemath If $C=\sum_{v\in A}v$ is the centroid and $\rho$ is the rotation, then you have $C=\rho C$ since $\rho$ just permutes the elements of $A$.  If $P\neq C$, then you get immediately that the rotation angle is zero (since what $\rho$ does to the ray $PC$ determines the rotation).

Comment: @user4506 There are link diagrams on $S^2$ with multiple axes of rotational symmetry.  Take a regular polyhedron as coffeemath mentions, then place link components on each face, and link them together along edges.  I think if you use a regular dodecahedron you can get 31 axes of rotation (and I'm guessing this is the maximum).

Answer (score 0):

Consider a link of four (unlinked) components: two small circles in the $yz$-planes perpendicular to the $x$-axis, with centers at each of $(\pm 1, 0, 0)$, and similarly, small circles in the $xz$-plane, with centers at $(0, \pm 1, 0)$.

There's an axis of rotational symmetry (the $z$-axis, with rotation by $\pi/2$). But rotation about either the $x$- or $y$-axis by $\pi$ is also a symmetry of this knot.

You can presumably enlarge the circles into ellipses and tilt them a little so that they link up into a chain and still have the same $x$- and $y$- symmetries, but it was easiest to describe in the unlinked case.

But maybe I'm missing what you mean by a symmetry in the link diagram. When you say "only one axis perpendicular to the plane through which rotational ...", there's surely only one direction perpendicular to some plane of symmetry. So is the only question whether there's only one point on the plane through which the symmetry line can pass? If so, then someone else's answer about the center of gravity seems spot-on.

Comment: I think I should add that the link diagram is connected. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I don't think that connectedness will kill my example. Moving to diagrams on $S^2$, let me use polar coords with $\phi$ as co-latitude and $\theta$ as longitude. Then the path
$$
\gamma(t) = (t, C \cos(2t))
$$
for $0 \le t \le 2\pi$, gives a diagram of the unknot on the surface of the 2-sphere -- it's sort of a "wave" around the equator. (Pick $C = 0.1$ or so).  There's clearly a rotational symmetry (by $\pi$) around the polar axis, but also one around the $x$- and $y$-axes, also by $\pi$. If you change the $2$ in the formula to any even number, you get more complex examples of the same thing.